# Javascript browser cookies taht will remember the value of turning odometer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to write browser cookies which will remember the value of turning odometer...so that each time the user visits the site again , the odometer will resume on the value on which odometer was at when the user left the site?

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/aht87opr/17/

Current value button outputs the current value, this value might come in handy when writting those cookies. Please help, I need to have this

```
    //<![CDATA[
        var n = 0;
        var myOdometer;
        function startcounting () {
            var div = document.getElementById("odometerDiv");
            myOdometer = new Odometer(div, {value: n, digits: 6, tenths: true});
    myOdometer.set(0);        
            update();
        }

        function update () {
            n=n+0.01
            myOdometer.set(n);
            setTimeout(update, 200);
        }
    //]]>

startcounting();
```

Comment: have you tried a JSON string?

Comment: and you'd probably be better off with localStorage instead of cookies

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley I found the following localStorage code http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/Hn7jc/ since I'm not good at javascript would you be kind enough to help me with adopting that script to my code  https://jsfiddle.net/aht87opr/17/ ?

Comment: sure thing, give me a minute to clean things up

Comment: ok, I'm still here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an updated Snippet of your code with a working localStorage Save Event](https://jsfiddle.net/nech0L9e/25/)

there are 4 important parts to my changes:

1) Use Object.assign instead of setting all the propertis, then looping through the options to overwrite what you just set

```
Object.assign(this, {
  digits: 6,
  tenths: 0,
  digitHeight: 40,
  digitPadding: 0,
  digitWidth: 30,
  bustedness: 2,
  fontStyle: "font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace; font-weight: 900;",
  value: -1,
}, options)
```

2) adding a save function to Odometer

```
var save = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('myOdometer', JSON.stringify(this))
}.bind(this)
```

3) adding a function to load save data or create a new odometer

```
Odometer.loadOrCreate = function(div, defaults){
  var saved = localStorage.getItem('myOdometer')
  console.log(saved)
  return new Odometer(div, (saved ? JSON.parse(saved) : defaults))
}
```

4) returning ONLY the functions that you will use outside of the odometer function. In javascript there is no such thing as a private function. You can however achieve privacy through closures (in this case returning an object that has only the functions you need)

```
return {
  get: get,
  set: set,
  save: save,
  run: run
}
```

The final piece of the puzzle is deciding when to save the users place. You don't want to over do it by saving every millisecond.  What I added to your snippet was an unload listener so that it saves changes before the tab closes

```
myOdometer = Odometer.loadOrCreate(div, {
  value: n,
  digits: 6,
  tenths: true
});
window.addEventListener('unload', myOdometer.save)
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort but is it supposed to remember the numbers after each jsfiddle refresh ? because when I reset jsfiddle it resets back to 0...

Comment: that's because you code uses 'n' instead of incrementing `this.value`. I've updated with a fully working version

Comment: can I ask you one last thing ? @TheRealMrCrowley

Comment: @ania_piszko Sure, What's that?